# Workaround or alternative to no static methods on an interface

Tags: c#, search, interface

I'm implementing some naive searching in my application, and searches will take place on a couple of different object types (Customer, Appointment, Activity, etc.). I'm trying to create an interface that will have types that are searchable. What I'd like to do is something like this:

```
public interface ISearchable
{
    // Contains the 'at a glance' info from this object 
    // to show in the search results UI
    string SearchDisplay { get; }

    // Constructs the various ORM Criteria objects for searching the through 
    // the numerous fields on the object, excluding ones we don't want values 
    // from then calls that against the ORM and returns the results
    static IEnumerable<ISearchable> Search(string searchFor);
}
```

I already have a concrete implementation of this on one of my domain model objects, but I'd like to extend it to others.

The problem is obvious: you can't have static methods on an interface. Is there another prescribed method to accomplish what I'm looking for, or is there a workaround?

Comment: By the sounds of it, what you want to do is search through an IEnumerable collection of ISearchable items, if this is the case then you will need 2 classes for each Customer, Appointment, Activity etc. One will be the collection (Customers, Appointment and Activity) : IEnumerable then apply the ISearchable to those collection classes and the requirement for static methods will go.

Comment: If you really just want a plain static method, then you're going to have to make a helper class to contain it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interfaces really specify the behavior of an object, not a class.  In this case, I think one solution is to separate this into two interfaces:

```
public interface ISearchDisplayable
{
    // Contains the 'at a glance' info from this object 
    // to show in the search results UI
    string SearchDisplay { get; }
}
```

and

```
public interface ISearchProvider
{
    // Constructs the various ORM Criteria objects for searching the through 
    // the numerous fields on the object, excluding ones we don't want values 
    // from then calls that against the ORM and returns the results
    IEnumerable<ISearchDisplayable> Search(string searchFor);
}
```

An instance of `ISearchProvider` is an object that does the actual searching, while an `ISearchDisplayable` object knows how to display itself on a search result screen.

Comment: This would require me to have an existing instance of the class(es) I want to search against. Which I won't have any of at search time.

Comment: @SnOrfus, yes, I am suggesting you change your design so that you call `Search` on an instance, rather than a class.

Comment: +1: I think I might combine this with mquander's suggestion of creating a SearchProvider helper class.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know the solution for C#, but according to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1724502/java-interface-static-method-workaround), Java seems to have the same problem and the solution is just to use a [singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) object.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you will need at least one other class, but ideally you would not need a separate class for each ISearchable.  This limits you to one implementation of Search(); ISearchable would have to be written to accommodate that.

```
public class Searcher<T> where T : ISearchable
{
    IEnumerable<T> Search(string searchFor);
}
```